# jenkins performacne plugin with pipeline project,Compare with specific build

Tags: performance, jenkins, plugins, jmeter

I have created jenkins pipeline project where running jmeter test.
here i am not able to find option /attribute which can be passed/added to **perfReport** command with which i can comparr current run with specific past build number.

current perfreport options i do see are

```
perfReport filterRegex: '', relativeFailedThresholdNegative: 1.2, relativeFailedThresholdPositive: 1.89, relativeUnstableThresholdNegative: 1.8, relativeUnstableThresholdPositive: 1.5, sourceDataFiles: 'results.csv'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following stanza to your pipeline:

```
modeEvaluation: true, nthBuildNumber: 1
```

change this `1` to the build number you would like compare the current result to.

More information:

- [Jenkins Pipeline Syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)
- [How to Use the Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin)
- [How to Build Reports with Peformance Plugin](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/Reporting.html)

Comment: thns Dmitri .. this answer resolves my query.